# Vuetify custom component for user profile

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, uicomponents

I want to build a custom profile component that looks like the LinkedIn user profile. As you can see there is a Card element, and then the avatar photo overlays it. How can I build such a component? I'm new to Vuejs/Vuetify. I looked for some examples online but couldn't find anything that explains what I need.

[image: User photo overlays the background card]

I appreciate your code snippet or suggestion.

Comment: i would suggest understand props, slots and template of `.vue` to understand how vue works as component. OpenClassroom is good place for learning everything about Vue.

Comment: thanks, I will. also any codepen example you can point me to for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their documentation I just took [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/avatars/#profile-card) example and modified it, however you may need to add different classes for styling since I couldn't make it responsive.

```
 <template>
      <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="434" tile>
          <v-img height="100%" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/server-room.jpg"></v-img>
          <v-col>
            <v-avatar size="100" style="position:absolute; top: 130px">
              <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/profiles/marcus.jpg"></v-img>
            </v-avatar>
          </v-col>
            <v-list-item color="rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)">
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="title">Marcus Obrien</v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>Network Engineer</v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
      </v-card>
    </template>
```

Comment: bottom 40 px is better for responsibility to see it from bottom

Answer (score 2):

I just Tried. I think you can do more batter.  [Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IKCN.png)

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="1000" tile>
      <v-img height="200" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/server-room.jpg"></v-img>
      <v-row style="margin:2.5%;position:absolute; top: 130px">

                  <v-list-item>
                   <v-list-item-avatar size="100">
                      <img
                        src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
                        alt="John"
                      >
                    </v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title class="title" style="margin-top:20px;">Injamamul Haque Sonet</v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle>Software Engineer | dokanee</v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-list-item>
    </v-row>
  </v-card>
</template>
```